# Cannot find moment components in angular

Tags: angular, momentjs

I am getting the below error when building my angular project using npm start. I tried to install dependencies using yarn command but it does not help.

This is the error message I am getting:

```
ERROR in ./src/AppPreBootstrap.ts 155:12-21
"export 'fn' (imported as 'moment') was not found in 'moment'
ERROR in ./src/AppPreBootstrap.ts 158:12-21
"export 'fn' (imported as 'moment') was not found in 'moment'
ERROR in ./src/AppPreBootstrap.ts 148:8-21
"export 'locale' (imported as 'moment') was not found in 'moment'
ERROR in ./src/AppPreBootstrap.ts 151:12-21
"export 'tz' (imported as 'moment') was not found in 'moment'
ERROR in ./src/app/shared/layout/themes/themes-layout-base.component.ts 47:26-36
"export 'utc' (imported as 'moment') was not found in 'moment'
```

Does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Comment: How did you import mement in code ? and What is your version of moment?Error is not enough to understand problem

Answer (score 0):

The import could look as follows:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Then you can use `moment` as shown below for example.

```
moment(time).format('D MMM YYYY HH:mm');
```